# How to use Box2D in Delphi

Tags: delphi, box2d

i use delphi rio to create Box2D
The world and gravity were created as follows when creating the form

```
  gravity := b2Vec2.Create(0.0, -10.0);
  world := b2WorldWrapper.Create(gravity);
  try
    groundBodyDef := b2BodyDef.Create();
    groundBodyDef.position.&Set(0.0, -10.0);
    groundBody := world.CreateBody(@groundBodyDef);
    groundBox := b2PolygonShapeWrapper.Create();
    groundBox.SetAsBox(50.0, 10.0);
    groundBody.CreateFixture(groundBox, 0.0);
  finally
  end;
```

and create Box when user click on Button1

```
var
  dynamicBox: b2PolygonShapeWrapper;
  fixtureDef: b2FixtureDef;
begin
  bodyDef := b2BodyDef.Create();
  bodyDef.&type := b2_DynamicBody;
  bodyDef.position.&Set(0.0, 4.0);
  body := world.CreateBody(@bodyDef);

  dynamicBox := b2PolygonShapeWrapper.Create();
  dynamicBox.SetAsBox(1.0, 1.0);

  fixtureDef := b2FixtureDef.Create();
  fixtureDef.shape := dynamicBox;
  fixtureDef.density := 1.0;
  fixtureDef.friction := 1.0;
  body.CreateFixture(@fixtureDef);

  dynamicBox.Destroy;
  groundBox.Destroy;
end;
```

and circle when click on Button2, RandomFloat() create random float number "Result := 2.0 * Random() - 1.0;"

```
var
  circle: b2CircleShapeWrapper;
  fd: b2FixtureDef;
  bd: b2BodyDef;
  shape: b2CircleShapeWrapper;
  p: b2Vec2;
  radius: Float32;
begin
  radius := 2.0;
  shape := b2CircleShapeWrapper.Create;
  shape.m_p := b2vec2.Create(0.0, 0.0);
  shape.m_radius := radius;

  fd := b2FixtureDef.Create;
  fd.shape := shape;
  fd.density := 1.0;
  fd.friction := 0.0;

  p := b2Vec2.Create(RandomFloat(), 3.0 + RandomFloat());
  bd := b2BodyDef.Create;
  bd.&type := b2_dynamicBody;
  bd.position := p;
  //bd.allowSleep := false;
  body := world.CreateBody(@bd);

  body.CreateFixture(@fd);
end;
```

But I could not display them in a TPaintBox

```
procedure TfrmMain.PaintBoxPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  rect: TRectF;
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Canvas.Fill.Color := b2Color2TColor(b2Color.Create(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1));
    rect := PaintBox.BoundsRect;
    Canvas.FillRect(rect, 0, 0, [], DEFAULT_OPACITY);

    g_debugDraw.Canvas := Canvas;
    g_debugDraw.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Yellow;
    g_debugDraw.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

I searched the internet but found nothing about how to use the Box2d in Delphi.
There are a few examples but they are complex and have no explanation and with their help it is not possible to learn the basics of use.

1)[box2d.org](https://box2d.org/documentation/index.html)

2)[embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Box2D_in_Delphi_Applications)

3)[fmxexpress](https://www.fmxexpress.com/box2d-physics-engine-for-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-on-android-ios-windows-and-osx/)

4)[vido of delphi sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBXFRBdCCXo&feature=youtu.be)

5)[githup port](https://github.com/nakijun/box2d-delphi)

6)[other port to delphi](https://code.google.com/archive/p/box2d-delphi/)

7)[pascalgamedevelopment](https://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/archive/index.php/t-4838.html)

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the reference to the few examples you found on the internet?

Comment: I found this resource: https://www.fmxexpress.com/box2d-physics-engine-for-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-on-android-ios-windows-and-osx/ Did you see it?

Comment: @fpiette
Yes
I have seen this before
This app also comes with new versions of Delphi

Comment: I suggest you select the sample that is closest to what you intend to do, study the code, compile and run it to be sure you have every piece in place. Then start modifying the sample to fit your need and then ask for SPECIFIC question where you don't understand. For the fundamentals of Box2D, I'm sure you have to read the original documentation to understand the concepts. The concepts doesn't change whatever programming language you use.